# Upload data from a grid by import scenarios

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I created a grid inside a tab in Stock Items screen and I would like to know whether it is possible to upload data from a simple grid by import scenarios.

any suggestion? 
Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's possible but I would recommend to use the import excel feature if it meets your requirements, it's much easier to use, no wizard configuration and template files required for this one: https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/12/enabling-upload-from-excel-for-the-grid.html

Comment: Thanks so much for the information Hugues, I will try to do it, have a nice day!